# Assign IPs to programs/processes

Tags: networking, routes, ip

I need to assign different IP addresses to different processes (mostly PHP & Ruby programs) running on my Linux server. They will be making queries to various servers, including the situation where processes connecting to the same external server should have different IPs.

How this can be achieved?

Any option (system wide, or PHP/Ruby-specific, using proxy servers etc) will suit me.

Comment: hi, did you find a way to achieve what you're looking for?

Comment: @LeonardoRick I ended up with setting nginx (reverse?) proxy. My programs would call something like `http://localhost:1024/proxy/for/ip1` instead of real URLs. On nginx's side, I used `proxy_bind` directive that allows to choose the IP address that is used for outcoming connections to "backend" - actually, to an external server in this setup.

Comment: that's awesome! This way you can ensure that each process use a single IP? Is that possible to run this kind of logic on AWS and similar? If you could provide some articles on this thread I'll be so much thankful. You could answer your own question with that information. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @LeonardoRick, I've added an answer with my solution for my original problem. Please upvote if you find both the question and the answer useful :) As for AWS, if your VM has several public IPs, I see no reasons why this should not work (although I'm not very familiar with AWS).

Comment: thanks a lot. It will be very helpfull

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @LeonardoRick request, I'm providing the details for the solution that I ended up with.

Say, I have a server with `172.16.0.1` and `172.16.0.2` IP addresses.

I set up `nginx` (on the same machine) with the configuration that was looking somewhat like this:

```
server {

      # NEVER EXPOSE THIS SERVER TO THE INTERNET, MAKE SURE PORT 10024 is not available from outside
      listen 127.0.0.1:10024;
      
      # block access from outside on nginx level as well
      allow 127.0.0.1;
      deny  all;
      
      # actual proxy rules
      location ~* ^/from-172-16-0-1/http(s?)\:\/\/(.*) {
            proxy_bind     172.16.0.1;
            proxy_pass     http$1://$2?$args;
      }   
      location ~* ^/from-172-16-0-2/http(s?)\:\/\/(.*) {
            proxy_bind     172.16.0.2;
            proxy_pass     http$1://$2?$args;
      }
}
```

*(Actually I cannot remember all the details now (this code is 'from whiteboard', it's not an actual working one), nevertheless it should represent all the key ideas. Check regexes before deployment).*
**Double-check that port 10024 is firewalled and not accessible from outside, add extra authentication if necessary. [Especially if you are running Docker](https://blog.viktorpetersson.com/2014/11/03/the-dangers-of-ufw-docker.html).**

This nginx setup makes it possible to run HTTP requests like
`http://127.0.0.1:10024/from-172-16-0-2/https://example.com/some-URN/object?argument1=something`

Once received a request, nginx will fetch the HTTP response from the requested URL using the IP specified by the corresponding `proxy_bind` directive.

Then - as I was running in-house or open-source software - I simply configured it (or altered its code) so it would perform requests like the one above instead of (original) `https://example.com/some-URN/object?argument1=something`.

All the management - what IP should be used at the moment - was also done by 'my' software, it simply selected the necessary `/from-172-16-0-XXX/` endpoint according to its business logic.

That worked very well for my original question/task. However, this may not be suitable for some other applications, where it could not be possible to alter the request URLs. However, a similar approach with setting some kind of proxy may work for those cases.

---

*(If you are not familiar with `nginx`, there are some starting guides [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-20-04) and [here](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/nginx-installation-and-basic-setup/))*

Answer (score 1):

The processes bind sockets (both incoming and outgoing) to an *interface* (or multiple interfaces), addressable by IP address, with various ports. In order to have them directly addressable by different IP addresses, you must have them bind their sockets to different NICs (virtual or hardware).

You could point each process to a proxy (configure the hostname of the server to be queried to be a different proxy for each process), in which case the external server will see the different IPs of the proxies. Otherwise, if you could directly configure the processes to use different NICs for their communications, that would be ideal.

You may need to make changes to the code to make this configurable (very often, programmers create outgoing TCP connections with convenience functions without specifying the NIC they will use, as they typically don't care). In PHP, you can use "socket_bind" to bind the endpoint to a nic, e.g. see the first example [in the docs for socket_bind](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-bind.php).

Comment: The situation is vice versa. I have no servers running on this machine, I have programs that connect to other servers. Those programs should connect from different IPs each.